# Bootstrap cap value and how it relates to fsw and duty cycle?

Tags: power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck, mppt

I am designing a synchronous buck converter with mppt. I have a question about the bootstrap capacitor value. Knowing that the duty cycle and fsw are dependent on this value. What is the best approach to this?

note that Vs of the high side switch is changing as the duty cycle change, thus the input voltage changes since its the solar panel voltage.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Bootstrap Capacitor Selection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18423/7036), [Calculation for the Boot Strap capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/189523/7036).  Application notes: [Fairchild AN-6076](http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/208/8372.AN_2D00_6076.pdf), [Bootstrap Circuit Design Manual](http://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/files/manuals/dipipm_bootstrap_circuit_e.pdf).

Comment: What is your low voltage supply for the bootstrap (typically +15 or something like that)?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany , it is 15V

Comment: The bootstrap cap doesn't really care about the input voltage, it cares about switching frequency and gate charge and duty cycle and **the difference between the 15V supply and Vos2**. When the cap is being charged that's the voltage. When it's being used, it is referenced to the source of Q1.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany now in my case, I assume the gate charge and switching frequency are constant, but for mppt, the duty cycle will change, what consideration do you think i have to take for that.

Comment: @abukhlad Use the formulas that Nick A. referenced.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany , thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The C_boost impedance must be lower than the load capacitance but not too much higher.

The first step is the capacitor C value must be bigger than the load, then it is charges up the V+ rail voltage on negative swings when the low side Nch FET conducts. The next step is an internal positive rectifier to make a charged voltage to drive the gate well above the V+ rail.( such that Vboost=Vgs=2~3*Vgs(th) to achieve low RdsOn). The low side PWM does the work of pumping the charge to the Boost cap for the high side Nch can start working.

But you know Q=CV so the formulae shows all the load charges that must be transferred by using a boost capacitance 2x or twice the maximum load.

Zc=(2pif*C)^-1 to capture most of the PWM swing, yet if it is too big that it overloads the negative Nch FET, unless there is some soft start.

This just gives some intuition to the formulae in the design manuals in comments.

Here is a simple capacitive divider to a step pulse to show a linear representation, even though the FET gate capacitance rises sharply at threshold voltage of conduction

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWm355.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your reply. Is this case true when the voltage is present like a battery?

Comment: Yes Cboot=Qtotal / ΔVboot  and Qtotal=Qgate + I(leakage) * t_on + Q_ic

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I really cannot figure out delta_Vboot and Q_ic. I assume I (leakage) is zero for ceramic. like for example, if Vin range is 37 to 18V and v_battery is 6 to 8V. I also see a lot of people paralleling Cboot capacitor with a electrolytic capacitor of some value?

Comment: ΔVboot is less than Vdd by the diode switch voltage drop   Qic is often given for the internal charge pump, if you follow best design examples in commercial solutions, that ought to be fine.

Comment: caps with 1us response time C*ESR might be ok but not 200us general e-caps purpose.

Comment: My rule of thumb is ESR*C < 5 / f (pwm)   thus different C and ESR values from 10kHz to 1MHz PWM

Comment: But I expect biggest charge comes from low RdsON switches with higher Ciss and Q so it is almost Qfet / Qbs cap = ΔVboot/Vdd * k for k slightly < 1

Comment: I really appreciate your very clear explanation. Thank you very much!